# Current User Task using CAML Qurey

Tags: caml-query, tasks

Here's my query to get current user task using CAML but it's not working

```
    SPUser me = web.CurrentUser;
    SPList list = web.Lists["Tasks"];
    SPQuery qurey = new SPQuery();
    qurey.Query = @"<Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='AssignedTo' />
    <Value Type='User'>"+ me.Name +"</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Status' /><Value Type='Choice'>Not Started</Value></Eq></And></Where>";
    SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(qurey);
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the tasks for the current user you should use a CAML query like:

```
<Where>
  <Or>
    <Eq>
      <FieldRef Name='AssignedTo' LookupId='TRUE'/>
      <Value Type='Integer'><UserID /></Value>
    </Eq>
    <Membership Type='CurrentUserGroups'>
      <FieldRef Name='AssignedTo'/>
    </Membership>
  </Or>
</Where>
```

like this:

```
query.Query = "<Where><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name='AssignedTo' LookupId='TRUE'/><Value Type='Integer'><UserID /></Value></Eq><Membership Type='CurrentUserGroups'><FieldRef Name='AssignedTo'/></Membership></Or></Where>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
  SPWeb oWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;
  string currentUser = oWeb.CurrentUser.Name;
  SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
  query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"AssignedTo\" /><Value Type='User'>" +        
  currentUser + "</Value></Eq></Where>"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SPWeb oWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;
string currentUser = oWeb.CurrentUser.Name;
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
query.Query = "<Where><Contains><FieldRef Name=\"AssignedTo\" /><Value Type='Text'>" +        
currentUser  + "</Value></Contains></Where>"
```